# Is it recommended to have multiple deployments of same application in same AWS region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I had a requirement where it might be possible I would need to support different versions of the application at the same time which is kind of a business requirement.
One way of doing this would be to deploy the app in different regions. But it might also be required to run the same app in one region multiple times.

Of course, it can be done by parameterising the deployment scripts but will it lead to some issues?

One I can think of is same app running in the same region might consume the same resources and it might hit some of the regional limits. Are there any other issues I should be aware of?

Answer (score -1):

We need more background information on your actual tech stack and more detailed requirements.

Running multiple versions of multiple deployments is something that a lot of companies manage on AWS. CI/CD pipelines and many other topics are very helpful, but I am fishing in the dark here. 
You can certainly run those multiple deployments in one region.

For a first start, have a look at [Elastic Beanstalk environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.environments.html):
"You can deploy multiple AWS Elastic Beanstalk environments when you need to run multiple versions of an application."

And [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.html) gets you started on Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: The tech stack is a combination of AWS managed services and Docker containers running on ECS. There are serverless components like Lambda, SQS, SNS.